# How to let user define custom properties in XAML?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

I want the user to be able to input a custom value for GradientStop.Color and GradientStop.Name? How would I do this?

````
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>0.5,0.5</RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Center>0.5,0.5</RadialGradientBrush.Center>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RadiusX>0.5</RadialGradientBrush.RadiusX>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RadiusY>0.5</RadialGradientBrush.RadiusY>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Opacity>0</RadialGradientBrush.Opacity>
                                <GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop.Color>White</GradientStop.Color>
                                    <GradientStop.Offset>0</GradientStop.Offset>
                                </GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop.Color>Blue</GradientStop.Color>
                                    <GradientStop.Offset>1.9</GradientStop.Offset>
                                </GradientStop>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Color you can change easily, but name suggests you're trying to do things back-to-front i.e. you have another part of the code that references by name and you want to cheat by changing this bit of code instead of the other bit. Try explaining in full exactly why you're trying to do this, there's almost certainly a better way than mucking around with element names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom,

If I were to do this, I would avoid doing any of it from xaml and instead do it programmatically.  By that, I mean in the code-behind, once you receive the user's custom value for Color and Name, I would build a new Style, RadialGradientBrush, etc. (basically everything you're doing in the xaml right now).  Then set the existing Rectangle's Style to this new Style that you created.

Comment: OK, so there is no XAML alternatives I understand?

Comment: For Color, you can do this with a Binding in XAML.  But if you're trying to change the Name property, I don't think that can be done in XAML.